# EF5 Visual design updating however model isnt

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-5

I am using VS2012 with EF5. I am using an existing database and making changes to the database. e.g. adding new tables and FK's

Adding the tables and FK's and updates seem to be applied within the designer of the edmx file however the actual code isnt updated.

Creating a new context I can't see my newly added tables.

Anyone else run into this problem, anyway to sort it?

Thank you!!

Comment: Fixed http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-visual-studio-2012-update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use *Run custom tool* from context menu on the template generating the code. There are some issues with automatic code generation in VS2012 - for example automatic generation does not happen if your EDMX is not in the root of your project.

Comment: Hi @Ladislav, I tried your suggestion but no luck. Should I not have it in a folder within the project?

Comment: Placing EDMX into and project's subfolder causes this issue but running custom tool manually every time you want to update the generated code should solve that.

Comment: Is there a bug raised on Microsoft Connect regarding this? I can confirm, I had this in the Models directory, but moving it back to root allowed it to work properly?!

Comment: @GONeale: The [bug is already](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/453) reported on EF's codeplex.

Comment: Bug fixed: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-visual-studio-2012-update